# Convert bytes extract from pabx grandstream to send in json in one webhook

Tags: python, json, zoho

I have the following data extracted from the pabx Grandstream:

```
b'\'625\',\'\',\'666\',\'0993057375\',\'outbound-route-2\',\'"" <546>\',\'PJSIP/666-00000463\',\'PJSIP/trunk_2-00000464\',\'Dial\',\'PJSIP/0993057375@trunk_2,,ThHKXM(record-check,StartMonitor)b(callee-handler^s^1)\',\'2023-08-30 18:37:57\',\'2023-08-30 18:37:58\',\'2023-08-30 18:37:58\',\'0\',\'0\',\'NO ANSWER\',\'DOCUMENTATION\',\'1693431477.2286\',\'Outbound\',\'666\',\'trunk_2\',\'s\',\'\',\'\',\'\',\'\',\'\',\'1693431477866658-666\',\'666\',\'DIAL\',\'\',\'NS500\',\n'
'625','','666','0993057375','outbound-route-2','"" <546>','PJSIP/666-00000463','PJSIP/trunk_2-00000464','Dial','PJSIP/0993057375@trunk_2,,ThHKXM(record-check,StartMonitor)b(callee-handler^s^1)','2023-08-30 18:37:57','2023-08-30 18:37:58','2023-08-30 18:37:58','0','0','NO ANSWER','DOCUMENTATION','1693431477.2286','Outbound','666','trunk_2','s','','','','','','1693431477866658-666','666','DIAL','','NS500',
```

As you can see, the Pabx system does not send keys, only values.

Then I created a list with the corresponding keys. The number of values ​​received from the pabx is always the same (36), so I adapted the list of keys to have the same number 36;

```
keys = ['Account Code', 'Adicional1', 'Caller Number', 'Callee Number', 'Context', 'CallerID Number', 'Source Channel', 'Dest. Channel', 'Last app.', 'Last date', 'Adicional2', 'Adicional3', 
            'Adicional4', 'Start Time', 'Answer Time', 'End Time', 'Call Time', 'Talk Time', 'Disposition', 'AMA Flags', 'Unique ID', 'Log Userfield', 'Adicional5', 'Dest Channel Extension', 'Adicional6', 'Caller Name', 
            'Adicional7', 'Answered by', 'Adicional8', 'Adicional9', 'Session', 'Premier Caller', 'Action Type', 'Source Trunk Name', 'Destination Trunk Name', 'Adicional10']
```

I tried to create a dictionary to unite the two pieces of information I have and send it via post in json, but without success. I always come up with a result that sends a single block of text.

Result received in Zoho Flow via webhook:

```
> webhookTrigger: {
      headers: {
         lb_request_id: "5c95e939696330771f635725a03811a8",
         accept_encoding: "gzip, deflate",
         lb_ssl_remote_ip: "200.155.175.36",
         lb_http_version: "HTTP/1.1",
         lb_ssl_session_resumption: ".",
         accept: "*/*",
         lb_ssl_ciphers: "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
         content_type: "application/json",
         host: "flow.zoho.com:443",
         lb_sni: "flow.zoho.com",
         connection: "close",
         content_length: "1278",
         user_agent: "python-requests/2.31.0",
         lb_ssl_version: "TLSv1.3"
      },
      payload: {
         data: [
            [
               "Account Code",
               "b'\\'599\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Adicional1",
               "\\'\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Caller Number",
               "\\'666\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Callee Number",
               "\\'0993057375\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Context",
               "\\'outbound-route-2\\'"
            ],
            [
               "CallerID Number",
               "\\'"" <546>\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Source Channel",
               "\\'PJSIP/666-00000430\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Dest. Channel",
               "\\'PJSIP/trunk_2-00000431\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Last app.",
               "\\'Dial\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Last date",
               "\\'PJSIP/0993057375@trunk_2"
            ],
            [
               "Adicional2",
               ""
            ],
            [
               "Adicional3",
               "ThHKXM(record-check"
            ],
            [
               "Adicional4",
               "StartMonitor)b(callee-handler^s^1)\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Start Time",
               "\\'2023-08-30 17:52:45\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Answer Time",
               "\\'2023-08-30 17:52:46\\'"
            ],
            [
               "End Time",
               "\\'2023-08-30 17:52:46\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Call Time",
               "\\'0\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Talk Time",
               "\\'0\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Disposition",
               "\\'NO ANSWER\\'"
            ],
            [
               "AMA Flags",
               "\\'DOCUMENTATION\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Unique ID",
               "\\'1693428765.2183\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Log Userfield",
               "\\'Outbound\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Adicional5",
               "\\'666\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Dest Channel Extension",
               "\\'trunk_2\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Adicional6",
               "\\'s\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Caller Name",
               "\\'\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Adicional7",
               "\\'\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Answered by",
               "\\'\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Adicional8",
               "\\'\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Adicional9",
               "\\'\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Session",
               "\\'1693428765542046-666\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Premier Caller",
               "\\'666\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Action Type",
               "\\'DIAL\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Source Trunk Name",
               "\\'\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Destination Trunk Name",
               "\\'NS500\\'"
            ],
            [
               "Adicional10",
               "\\n'"
            ]
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I tried to convert the two information and after joining them in a dict

I tried to send only the data received from the pabx just using encode on it (this result sends in text block too)

I'm new to Python and I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Combine

- a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html#dict) `{x: x ** 2 for x in range(10)}` with
- a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html#list): `[x for x in iterable]`,

e.g. as follows:

```
import json

pabx = b'\'625\',\'\',\'666\',\'0993057375\',\'outbound-route-2\',\'"" <546>\',\'PJSIP/666-00000463\',\'PJSIP/trunk_2-00000464\',\'Dial\',\'PJSIP/0993057375@trunk_2,,ThHKXM(record-check,StartMonitor)b(callee-handler^s^1)\',\'2023-08-30 18:37:57\',\'2023-08-30 18:37:58\',\'2023-08-30 18:37:58\',\'0\',\'0\',\'NO ANSWER\',\'DOCUMENTATION\',\'1693431477.2286\',\'Outbound\',\'666\',\'trunk_2\',\'s\',\'\',\'\',\'\',\'\',\'\',\'1693431477866658-666\',\'666\',\'DIAL\',\'\',\'NS500\',\n'
keys = ['Account Code', 'Adicional1', 'Caller Number', 'Callee Number', 'Context', 'CallerID Number', 'Source Channel', 'Dest. Channel', 'Last app.', 'Last date', 'Adicional2', 'Adicional3', 
        'Adicional4', 'Start Time', 'Answer Time', 'End Time', 'Call Time', 'Talk Time', 'Disposition', 'AMA Flags', 'Unique ID', 'Log Userfield', 'Adicional5', 'Dest Channel Extension', 'Adicional6', 'Caller Name', 
        'Adicional7', 'Answered by', 'Adicional8', 'Adicional9', 'Session', 'Premier Caller', 'Action Type', 'Source Trunk Name', 'Destination Trunk Name', 'Adicional10']
pabx_list = pabx.decode().split(',')

dictdata = [[{keys[x]: pabx_list[x]}] for x in range(len(keys))]
print(json.dumps({'data': dictdata},indent=4))
```

or

```
dictdata = [[keys[x], pabx_list[x]] for x in range(len(keys))]
print(json.dumps({'data': dictdata},indent=4))
```